# Get only non-filtered data from dc.js chart (dimension / group)

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

So this is a question regarding a rather specific problem. As I know from Gordon, main contributor of dc.js, there is no support for elasticY(true) function for logarithmic scales.

So, after knowing this, I tried to implement my own solution, by building a workaround, inside dc.js's renderlet event. This event is always triggered by a click of the user onto the barchart. What I wanted to do is this:

```
let groupSize = this.getGroupSize(fakeGroup, this.yValue);
let maximum = group.top(1)[0].value;
let minimum = group.top(groupSize)[groupSize-1].value;

console.log(minimum, maximum);

chart.y(d3.scale.log().domain([minimum, maximum])
  .range(this.height, 0)
  .nice()
  .clamp(true));
```

I thought, that at this point the "fakeGroup" (which is just group.top(50)) contains only the data points that are NOT filtered out after the user clicked somewhere. However, this group always contains all data points that are in the top 50 and doesn't change on filter events.

What I really wanted is get all data points that are NOT filtered out, to get a new maximum and minimum for the yScale and rescale the yAxis accordingly by calling chart.y(...) again.

Is there any way to get only data rows that are still in the chart and not filtered out. I also tried using remove_empty_bins(group) but didn't have any luck with that. Somewhere is always all() or top() missing, even after giving remove_empty_bins both functions.

Comment: I think this is fundamentally the wrong question (points for trying but I think this is a rabbit-hole). But I figured out a workaround to get log scales working without modifying dc.js - [see the issue for log scales](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/477).

Comment: Yeah I was getting kinda tired working on this, tried your link too, but couldn't get it to work. I have, however, found a SOLUTION. You have to re-define the scale in the preRedraw event listener, then it adjusts everything exactly as wanted.

Comment: I fixed my code on that issue. Considered posting a follow-up answer, but it's still the wrong question. The right question is: how do I do logarithmic Y scales in dc.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved it:

I made a function called rescale(), which looks like this:

```
rescale(chart, group, fakeGroup) {
let groupSize = this.getGroupSize(fakeGroup, this.yValue);

let minTop = group.top(groupSize)[groupSize-1].value;
let minimum = minTop > 0 ? minTop : 0.0001;
let maximum = group.top(1)[0].value;

chart.y(d3.scale.log().domain([minimum, maximum])
  .range(this.height, 0)
  .nice()
  .clamp(true));}
```

I think the parameters are pretty self-explanatory, I just get my chart, the whole group as set by dimension.group.reduceSum and a fake group I created, which contains the top 50 elements, to reduce bar count of my chart.

The rescale() method is called in the event listener

```
chart.on('preRedraw', (chart) => {
  this.rescale(chart, group, fakeGroup);
}
```

So what I do is re-defining (re-setting min and max values regarding filtered data) the charts yAxis everytime the chart gets redrawn, which happens to also be every time one of my charts is filtered. So now, the scale always fits the filtered data the chart contains after filtering another chart.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution! I guess we must have been talking about different problems, because in the issue linked above, nothing displays at all. Yes, definitely `preRedraw` is a good place to define custom min/max for custom elastic.

Comment: Oh sorrry, I didn't realise, otherwise I would've told you. Yeah, this works perfectly for my current problem. Needed to do some research and experimenting, but finally it works!